# is it possible to use google maps markers as checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to use Google Maps as multiple locations picker. Is it possible to make map markers selectable and use it in form for submission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "fake" this by assigning an `onclick` event handler to the icon. Create a [custom marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons) with an empty check box image in it, and then [assign an `onclick` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) that:

- A) Swaps the icon with an identical icon with a checkbox checked icon
- B) Creates or modifies a hidden `input` field somewhere else on the page which can be used for logic